# Issues on displaying Toast within onPostExecute of AsyncTask class

Tags: android

There are lot of questions regarding this problem in this forum but not of them worked for me. So I am asking this problem here. I am trying to read the data from MySQL database. After successfully fetching the data from database using PHP web service, I want to display the data. But when I used Toast for this, Eclipse prevent me to write the Toast command and displays me the error

> The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is
>   not applicable for the arguments (VersionReader, String, int)

The Java code for this is:

```
public class VersionReader extends AsyncTask<URI, Integer, Integer>{

    private String TAG = "RESULT";

    int version = 0;
    int local_version = 0;
    public VersionReader(int local_version){
        this.local_version = local_version;
    }
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(URI... urls) {
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(urls[0]);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            version = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return version;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(this, "The lastest version is " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Do anyone have any idea how can I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Constructor like:

```
Context ctx;

public VersionReader(int local_version , Context c){
    this.local_version = local_version;
    this.ctx = c;
}
```

Now use this ***ctx*** variable in your ***Toast***.

```
Toast.makeText(ctx, "The lastest version is " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace

```
Toast.makeText(this, "The lastest version is " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

with

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The lastest version is " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

note: valid if your `VersionReader` class is inside `Activity`

as your `VersionReader` class is not insode `Activity` or `Service`, create a a `Context` global variable in your class and acquire it from Constructor...

```
private Context context;

public VersionReader(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

and in `onPostExecute()`, use

```
Toast.makeText(context, "The lastest version is " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change  ,because here `this` resembles to `VersionReader` asynctask

```
Toast.makeText(this, "The lastest version is " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "The lastest version is " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**OR**

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The lastest version is " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**EDIT**

```
public class VersionReader extends AsyncTask<URI, Integer, Integer>{

    private Context context;
    public VersionReader(Context context) {
            this.context = context; 
    }
    // Blah blah
    // Then use the context any where
}
```

Comment: This class is not inside activity :(

Comment: Then use the **context** instead!!

Comment: If your Toast located class is not extending **context** , Then pass the context refernce to the constructor of the **VersionReader** while invoking the async task,

Answer (score 0):

onPreExecute(),onPostExecute(Result), are invoked on the ui thread. So you can display toast here.

```
 Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "The lastest version is " + result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

For clarity check the [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
   Toast.makeText(this, "The lastest version is " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

by the

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The lastest version is " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `this` refers to **VersionReader Class** not your **Activity**. So replace

```
Toast.makeText(this, "The lastest version is " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

with

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The lastest version is " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `getApplicationContext()`

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The lastest version is " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

because AsyncTask runs in background even after you destroy your Activity. so if you use **ActivityName.this** than it will find Activity refrence even after destroying activity. so it will give error.